# "What colour does not exist in the afterlife?" answer to an ARG riddle

Tags: riddle, alternate-reality-game

So there's an ARG that started on the Unfiction forums where you have to email a secret to a particular email address. One member has done this and received:

"CLEVER?

6* 83:.; ]45; 59 6

YOU MAY CONTACT US WITH YOUR ANSWER. 
A HINT WILL BE PROVIDED IF ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY."

The only real headway so far is that it may be some sort of keyboard substitution cipher, but what I'm really looking for help with is the riddle I received when I emailed it, which is completely different:

"IDENTITY IS IN THE EYE OF THE BEHOLDER.

ANSWER THIS: WHAT COLOUR DOES NOT EXIST IN THE AFTERLIFE?"

A couple of the suggestions I've received so far have been "green" (the colour of life), "black" (the colour of nothing, not on the RGB spectrum) and "time" (assuming the answer is more metaphorical) but honestly I don't have a clue. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this an ongoing contest?

Comment: @Forklift As far as I know, yes. The email address is still active and I assume that once I manage to figure out the answer to this I'll be sent another clue.

Comment: Our site rules actually prohibit soliciting help for ongoing contests, I'm afraid. https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1675/36638

Comment: It's not a contest though, there's no prize.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure about that. I will not vote to close then :)

Comment: I suppose I can see why ARGs and things like that would be a grey area. To be honest the only reason I posted it on Stack in the first place is that I can't post about it on the Unfiction forums (because for some reason I didn't get the activation email for my account) and you guys are the next best thing for figuring out cryptic clues.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I think this is a completely different puzzle and then poster thinks.
IDENTITY IS IN THE EYE OF THE BEHOLDER is the clue

IDENTITY (subset)) THE EYE OF THE BEHOLDER
and what part of COLOUR is not a subset of  THE AFTERLIFE

here is a sample solution I can think of.  We use the set as a range of letters so 
THE EYE OF THE BEHOLDER has letters that span the alphabet from E to Y
every letter in IDENTITY fits in that range

THE AFTERLIFE has letters A to R
What part COLOUR does not fit, note how it's oddly spelled British?

The U

Answer (score -1):

I'm almost certain that the first sentence is related to your "secret", as mine is "THE PAST IS UNCHANGING. FORWARDS IS THE ONLY WAY." So as far as I can tell, that's not relevant to the question, but I've been wrong about these things before.

I answered "none", personally.

Edit: I'm not sure why I'm being downvoted, especially since my answer was correct, and also gave context to a solution that the other answer got wrong. But hey. I'm not hurt by it.

Comment: I got it right, but I'm prohibited from talking about it according to the response I got. Can you let the Unfiction guys know I got the answer but I can't post because I never got an account activation email?

Comment: @JohnClifford Why not just ask for another account activation email?

Comment: @Rubio There doesn't appear to be any way to request one on the site. I tried signing up with a different email address but I still didn't get an activation email, and I can't PM an admin without being logged in.

Comment: I'll ask about the activation emails. If it's something happening to multiple accounts people will want to know.